# Is it possible to have computed function in RactiveJS?

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

Is there any way to run a computed property with an argument? Pretty much a computed function.

JS code

```
computed: {
            IsShapeToolSelected: function (toolId) {
               return toolId == this.get("QueryTool.QueryByShapeTool") ? "selected-tool" : "";
            }
          }
```

Html

```
<button on-click='draw: {{0}}' type="button" class="btn btn-default {{IsShapeToolSelected(0)}}">
   <span style="font-size:18px;">&#9679;</span>
   <br />
   <span>point</span>
</button>
<button on-click='draw: {{1}}' type="button" class="btn btn-default {{IsShapeToolSelected(1)}}">
   <img src="Content/imgs/idv.MapTools_Reports/line-24x24.png" />
   <br />
   <span>line</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to run a computed property with an argument?

No, but there are other solutions for your problem:

```js
computed: {
    IsShapeToolSelected: function () {
        return (function (toolId) {
            return toolId == this.get("QueryTool.QueryByShapeTool") ? "selected-tool" : "";
        }).bind(this);
    }
}
```

or

```js
data: {
    IsShapeToolSelected: function (toolId) {
        return toolId == this.get("QueryTool.QueryByShapeTool") ? "selected-tool" : "";
    }
}
```

or

```js
computed: {
    // use IsShapeToolSelected.1 instead of IsShapeToolSelected(1)
    IsShapeToolSelected: function () {
        var obj = {};
        obj[this.get("QueryTool.QueryByShapeTool")] = "selected-tool";
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: nice! the first one nailed it.